# I want to increase text size in a word file using python

Tags: python-3.x, python-docx

When i u\was building a project for a customer. An error occured that when i increased font_size in docx file in python using python-docx. It moved to a new line. I can't find any solution as to how to solve my problem.

Here is the the code:

```
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfilename
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Pt
from docx.oxml import OxmlElement
from docx.oxml.ns import nsdecls
import docxedit



def increase_text_size(paragraph, run, font_size):
    new_run = paragraph.add_run()
    new_run.text = run.text.replace(run.text, '')
    new_run.font.size = Pt(font_size)

document = Document(askopenfilename())
next = -1

for i1, table in enumerate(document.tables):
    for i2, row in enumerate(table.rows):
        for i3, cell in enumerate(row.cells):
            # print(dir(cell))
            for i4, paragraph in enumerate(cell.paragraphs):
                paragraph.paragraph_format.space_after = 0
                if 'Product Details' == paragraph.text:
                    # del document.tables[i1].rows[i2].cells[i3].paragraphs[i4]
                    docxedit.remove_paragraph(paragraph)
                elif 'SKU' in paragraph.text:
                    if '_' in paragraph.text:
                        next = 0
                        # paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('SKU  Size    Qty Color   Order No.', '')
                    else:
                        next = 1
                if next == 0:
                    for run in paragraph.runs:
                        # print(run.text)
                        # font = run.font
                        # font.size = Pt(14)
                        increase_text_size(paragraph, run, 110)
                if next != -1: next -= 1
document.save('resume.docx')
```

Here is the link to the input file: [input](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1baW8ORyDLbmaShdrySx3OnNgcW8sLjnU?usp=sharing)

Please help me resolve this issue.

I tried the normal way and also played with some parameters but no result.